# Building a quiz app in react. When clicking to the answers, background color is changing for all four answers

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo } from "react";

function QuizPage({ item }) { const [color, setColor] = React.useState(false); console.log(item.id);

function handleClick() { setColor((prev) => !prev);   }

const styles = { backgroundColor: color ? "teal" : "", color: color ? "white" : "",   };

return (
    <div className="quiz--page">
      <h1>{item.question}</h1>
      <div className="answer-btn">
        <button onClick={handleClick} style={styles}>
          {item.correct_answer}
        </button>
        {item.incorrect_answers.map((ia, index) => (
          <button key={index} onClick={handleClick} style={styles}>
            {ia}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <hr className="solid"></hr>
    </div>   ); }

export default QuizPage;


import React from "react"; import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; import QuizPage from "./components/QuizPage"; import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

function App() { const [state, setState] = useState(false); function startQuiz() { setState((prev) => !prev);   }

https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5

const [allQuizzes, setAllQuizzes] = useState([]);

useEffect(function () { console.log("Effect ran"); fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => { let quizzes = data.results; quizzes = quizzes.map((curQuiz) => { const id = nanoid();

return { ...curQuiz, id: id };
        }); setAllQuizzes(quizzes);
      }); []); console.log(allQuizzes); const apiResults = allQuizzes.map((item) => { return <QuizPage item={item} key={item.id} />;   }); return (
    <main>
      {state ? (
        <>
          <section>{apiResults}</section>
          <button className="check">Check answers</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <div className="starting--page">
          <h1>Quizzical</h1>
          <p>Solve problems</p>
          <button onClick={startQuiz} className="start--btn"> Start Quiz
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </main>   ); }

export default App;
```

Comment: Please format your code and fix the syntax error. `{ ...curQuiz, id: id };
  17 |             }); setAllQuizzes(quizzes);
> 18 |           }); []);` unexpected token.

Comment: You appear to have `handleClick() { setColor((prev) => !prev); }` running on every button click, I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen/not happen. Please add a text description, a title + code isn't enough to fully explain a problem.